# is "ASP.NET Membership" still a good choice for ASP.NET MVC authentication nowdays?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, membership-provider

The last time I used asp.net 4 years ago, the "ASP.Net Membership provider" was the best way to do user authentication in an ASP.Net application.

Nowadays, is using the "ASP.Net Membership provider" still a good way of authenticating users in an ASP.Net MVC application or is there something new for this purpose?

Is the "ASP.Net Membership provider" outdated?

Comment: What do you mean by "good," "best" and "efficient?" State your specific criteria.

Comment: I edited the question, I asking if there is another way to do it now days.

Comment: Asp.Net Identity is the new framework for it. Solves some of the problems with Membership.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Asp.Net Membership is a bit outdated. [Asp.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) was introduced a few years ago to help solve some of the pain points with the older system.

It supports third party OAuth through Google (and custom OAuth providers), 2 factor authentication, and easily extending the default schema via Entity Framework code first. It's really quite nice out of the box for 99% of applications though.

---

**Note to future readers:** *This was written in 2016. If you're reading this in the far flung future, please research current methods and post an up to date answer.*

Comment: In fact it's not possible to use ASP.Net Membership on the new ASP.Net Core platform at all.